# How to clone an inherited object?

Tags: c#, cloning

I've got a `Tile` class with this method:

```
    public object Clone()
    {
        return MemberwiseClone();
    }
```

And another class `Checker` that inherits from `Tile`.

I also have a `Board` class that is a `List<Tile>`. I want to clone the board, so I wrote this:

```
    public Board Clone()
    {
        var b = new Board(width, height);
        foreach (var t in this) b.Add(t.Clone());
        return b;
    }
```

But it throws an error:

> cannot convert from 'object' to 'Checkers.Tile'

Now I can make the `Tile.Clone` method return a `Tile` instead, but then will the `MemberwiseClone` copy the additional properties in the sub-`Checker` as well?

---

If that's not the problem, what's the semantic difference between the above `Board.Clone` method and this?

```
    public Board Clone()
    {
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            var bf = new BinaryFormatter();
            bf.Serialize(ms, this);
            ms.Position = 0;
            return (Board)bf.Deserialize(ms);
        }
    }
```

Because they're definitely having different effects on my program, even though when I print the board it *looks* the same. I don't think something is being *cloned* but a reference is being returned. The `Board` ctor looks like this:

```
    public Board(int width = 8, int height = 8)
    {
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        this.rowWidth = width / 2;
        this.Capacity = rowWidth * height;
    }
```

---

The `Tile` class actually doesn't have any properties. The checker just has two enums properties:

```
public enum Color { Black, White };
public enum Class { Man, King };

public class Checker : Tile
{
    public Color Color { get; set; }
    public Class Class { get; set; }
```

Comment: Extended my answer w.r.t. your edit.

Comment: How does your program behave differently?

Comment: @Heinzi: Causes this problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3647924/why-does-this-code-give-two-different-outputs-for-what-appears-to-be-the-same-i

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, [MemberwiseClone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.object.memberwiseclone.aspx) will also copy the `Checker`-only fields. MemberwiseClone cannot know the return type of your `Clone` method; therefore, it's behaviour cannot depend on it.

---

About the difference betweeen your Clone implementation and the serialization: `MemberwiseClone` creates a *shallow copy* of the Tiles: If a Tile (or Checker) references some object, the Tile's clone still references the *same* object (rather than a copy of it).

On the other hand, your serialization code is a [well known practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201957) for creating a *deep copy* of your board: The whole tree of dependent objects is serialized and deserialized.

Of course, this only makes a difference if your Tiles (or Checkers) contain fields with reference types.

Comment: `MemberwiseClone` should be able to copy enum types, no?

Comment: @Mark: Sure. Internally, enums are just `int` s.

Comment: Then I still don't know why the cloning wasn't working correctly. But I guess no one can answer that without more code... I'll just close this as the serialization works well enough for now, albeit it seems a bit inefficient.

Answer (score 2):

As I see it, there are four main classes of object, with respect to cloning:

1. Those which cannot be cloned without breaking something

   Those which make no public promise of cloneability, but can be nicely cloned using MemberwiseClone

   Those which make no public promise of cloneability, but can be cloned via some means other than MemberwiseClone

   Those which publicly advertise cloneability on behalf of themselves and derived classes.

Unfortunately, there's generally no nice way to distinguish #1 and #2 unless a type obscures the MemberwiseClone method.  I like to refer to type #3 as semi-cloneable.

A semi-cloneable object should support a protected virtual method called something like CloneBase which will return either Object or the base class type (it won't matter much in practice); the lowest-level CloneBase method should call MemberwiseClone and do whatever is necessary to fix up the cloned object.  Any derived class which supports cloning should have a public Clone method which simply calls CloneBase and typecasts the result.  Any derived-class logic necessary to fix up and object after base-class-level cloning should go in an override of CloneBase.

If there may be any need for a derived class which does not support cloning, then make public a semi-cloneable class and inherit from that class a CloneableWhatever which does nothing except add the public Clone method.  In that way, non-cloneable classes can derive from the semi-cloneable class, and cloneable ones can derive from CloneableWhatever.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it will - it's [polymorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_polymorphism).