# Will memberwiseclone also copy members defined in derived class?

Tags: c#, copy, clone

I need to define a Clone() method that does shallow copy. (No deep copy needed)

But I need that to copy derived class' members of as well.

If I had

```
class Base {
     int baseMember;
     public (virtual?) Base Clone() {
         return (Base)this.MemberwiseClone()
     }
}
```

then should I derive all other classes for Clone()?
Will derivedMember also be copied by Base.Clone()?

```
class Derived {
    int derivedMember;  //will this also be copied by base.Clone()?

    //Necessary?
    public new Derived (override Base?) Clone() {
        return (Derived)this.MemberwiseClone();
    }
}
```

Comment: `MemberwiseClone()` is the same function no matter which function you call it from.

Comment: well since `Clone` returns `Base` its wont include anything from `Derived`, may be better to implement `IClonable` and return `object` from your clone method

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Will derived (nonstatic) fields also be copied when calling `this.MemberwiseClone()` on its base class?**

Yes, they will as you can assure yourself by writing a little test like this one:

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Student a = new Student() { Name = "John Doe", Id = 1 };
    Student b = (Student)a.Clone();
}

public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual Person Clone()
    {
        return (Person)this.MemberwiseClone();
    }
}

public class Student:Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

Additionally this question was already [answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3648002/1409903).

**Do I need to override (or rewrite) the `Clone` method in the derived class?**

Technically it's not necessary, but as you see you have to cast the result since the return type of the `base.Clone()` method is `Person`.

Alternatively you could rewrite your base class `Clone()` method like this:

```
public T Clone<T>() where T:Person
{
    return (T)this.MemberwiseClone();
}
```

Then you need to call

```
Student b = a.Clone<Student>();
```

on your derived classes. So you only have to write the clone method once in the base class. Although I'm not sure if this is the best solution.

Comment: Expounding upon this answer, another option to reduce the need to pass the generic on the method is to update the base class to provide your sub-class. `public class Person<T> { ... }` and `public class Student : Person<Student> { ... }`. Then subclasses can just call `.Clone()`